# Sync ALTER TABLE ... DELETE on all replicas of a Clickhouse cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, synchronous, clickhouse, alter-table

**TL;DR**

There are 2 questions:

1. How to correctly do a synchronous `ALTER TABLE .. DELETE` on a Clickhouse cluster.
2. Will data be deleted from all replicas when using `ALTER TABLE .. DELETE` with `mutations_sync = 2` settings and without using `ON CLUSTER`. Or how could this be verified

**Long**

There are 2 CH installations: single-server (H1) and cluster (3 nodes, H2). I have created a table foo with the engines: H1 - ReplacingMergeTree, H2 - ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree (using `ON CLUSTER bar`). Then I make requests:
For each request, I generated 1kk rows (about 200 MB was obtained approximately).

1. Request to H1 (single-server)

```
clickhouse-client -h $H1 --queries-file=queries.sql

queries.sql:

ALTER TABLE foo DELETE WHERE 1 SETTINGS mutations_sync = 0;

SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 1
```

The result of `SELECT` shows some record, that hasn't been deleted yet. Stand to reason.

2. Do the same, but with `mutations_sync = 1`. The `SELECT` returned 0 rows. Same with `mutations_sync = 2`. So far, everything is as expected.
3. Request to H2 (cluster):

```
clickhouse-client -h $H2 --queries-file=queries.sql

queries.sql:

ALTER TABLE foo ON CLUSTER bar DELETE WHERE 1 SETTINGS mutations_sync = 2;

SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 1
```

The `SELECT` returns some record, although it seems it shouldn't, since `mutations_sync = 2` means that the request must complete on all replicas before it is finished (or am I misunderstanding something?)

4. Do the same, but remove `ON CLUSTER bar` from `ALTER TABLE`. In this case, the result of `SELECT` is 0 rows.

I assume that the reason of such behavior in case 3 is due to when the `ON CLUSTER` option is used, the request goes to ZooKeeper, and immediately complete because ZK just gets the request to send it to all replicas, but don't wait for its completion. Is that right?

I want to check if data is deleted from all replicas in case 4. I've tried making requests like:

```
#!/bin/bash

clickhouse-client -h $H2_REPLIC1 --query="ALTER TABLE topics ON CLUSTER dc2_test DELETE WHERE 1 SETTINGS mutations_sync = 0";
clickhouse-client -h $H2_REPLIC2 --query="SELECT * FROM topics LIMIT 1 FORMAT TabSeparated";
```

But both using `mutations_sync = 0` and `mutations_sync = 2`, the `SELECT` returns 0 rows (even if increase number of generated rows in foo to 30kk). I don't understand this behavior, so I can't get the answer to my 2nd question (in TL;DR)

Answer (score 1):

1. No way.
2. No.

Mutations were implemented as an ADMIN operations to solve GDPR problem, but not daily basis business (USER) tasks.
That's why mutations don't not provide consistency / atomicity.
And that's why mutations are very unreliable if you are trying to use them to solve business logic tasks (USER tasks).

Comment: In this case why clickhouse have implemented the `mutations_sync` parameter?

Comment: @crak it is funny, but in the first place they implemented mutations_sync for CI tests to be able to test `alter table` during Clickhouse development.